# How to run logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, interpretation, regression

I am getting very confused at my data.
I want to run a simple logistic regression:
IV is called FIRST_cat: High or Low (grouping on a questionnaire)
DV is called InsomniaT3: High or Low(Grouping on a questionnaire)
Both are scored as factors on R.

Code sample below:

```
REGRESSION <- glm(InsomniaT3 ~ FIRST_cat, data = tidydata, 
                  family = "binomial"(logit))
summary(REGRESSION)


## Output:
Call:
glm(formula = InsomniaT3 ~ FIRST_cat, family = binomial(logit), 
    data = tidydata)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.3964  -0.8532   0.9732   0.9732   1.5409  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    -0.8232     0.2827  -2.911  0.00360 ** 
FIRST_catHigh   1.3247     0.3425   3.868  0.00011 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 239.68  on 172  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 223.67  on 171  degrees of freedom
AIC: 227.67

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

I don't understand this output at all. Could someone explain if this is correct? Do i have to dummy code variables? Also when i add in other continuous predictors, they don't seem to show up in the output.

Comment: If variables are factors in R, `glm()` will dummy code them automatically.  The coefficient for `FIRST_catHigh` is the coefficient for the dummy variable where `FIRST_cat` is equal to `High`.

Comment: HI ben, i managed to work out the code. I was using commas instead of +'s

Answer (score 0):

As you are using factors, glm automatically uses dummy variables to estimate your coefficients. It created 2 dummies: one for `FIRST_cat = "High"`, named `FIRST_catHigh`, and other for `FIRST_cat = "Low"`, but as you can't add both on the model (because of multicolinearity problems), it uses only one.

The coefficient associated with the intercept can now be interpreted as:

```
E[InsomniaT3 | FIRST_cat = "Low"]
```

And the associated with the `FIRST_catHigh` can be interpreted as:

```
E[InsomniaT3 | FIRST_cat = "High"] - E[InsomniaT3 | FIRST_cat = "Low"]
```

Comment: Thanks- but could someone explain to me how to interpret this when writing it up, and also how can i get goodness of fit statistics.

Comment: What do you mean by "writing it up?". If you click on your `REGRESSION` object it opens a list of elements it contains, some of them are goodness of fit statistics. You can get those numbers by code using `REGRESSION$name.of.the.item`, for example, you can get the AIC by `REGRESSION$aic`.

Comment: Hi thanks. What i mean is the AIC is 227.67 but i am not sure how to interpret that. When i google i find confusing answers. Also in regards to writing it up, I want to say something like FIRST CAT was significant, such that being in the high group increases.... but i am not sure how it is interpreted.

Comment: The AIC formula is: `n*ln(Sum of Squared Residuals) + 2*k` where n is the number of observations and k is the number of parameters. A bigger SSR means that your model doesn't fit well the data, so you're looking for the model with the minimal AIC you can find. But AIC also accounts for the size of the model: for example, If you add a variable that didn't makes the fit better (SSR remained constant) your k increases and so the statistic, which is bad. It is hard to interpret AIC by itself, but it is optimal to compare AIC's of different models.

Comment: From the output you presented in your question you can look at the coefficients table to learn about significance: `FIRST_catHigh` had a positive estimation of `1.3247` and in a statistical sense, is different from 0 (that's the test that the model automatically do) with probability `0.00011`, which is below the usual 5% level, so considered significant. As i said in my comment, that coefficient means `E[InsomniaT3 | FIRST_cat = "High"] - E[InsomniaT3 | FIRST_cat = "Low"]`, so the "being in the high group" has the outcame affected by `FIRST_catHigh - (intercept)` = 2.1479

Answer (score 0):

1. When writing it up, you should interpret the model as follows. Your
   variable "FIRST_cat" was significant, you can reject the null
   hypothesis that it is equal to zero. If that variable is "high" it
   has a positive effect, otherwise a negative effect. Furthermore, that means that the probability of "InsomniaT3" being "high" increases/decreases (depending on how it is coded).
2. AIC is a measurement of how well your model can predict unobserved
   data, *relative* to other models on the same data. If you have only
   applied one model to your data, the AIC provides no valuable
   information. If you compare several models, you want your AIC to be as low as possible.
3. As for other goodness of fit statistics, you could check for multicolinarity (VIF values). You can check model assumptions, such as linear dependeancy on the logit scale for your predictors. You can check for outliers in your data (Cook's distance).